# Como comparar os valores de uma coluna com a média desses valores em SQL?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Tenho uma coluna de livros, e quero mostrar apenas os livros que o preço é maior que a média desses preços, como fazer isso? O nome da minha coluna é `price`, e não consigo colocar um `where price > avg(price)`, nem um `having price > avg(price)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode calcular a média antes e atribuir a uma variável:

```
DECLARE @media numeric(15, 2);

SELECT @media = AVG(l.price)
  FROM livros l;

SELECT l.*
  FROM livros l
 WHERE l.price > @media;
```

Ou realizar um `CROSS JOIN` com o valor calculado:

```
SELECT l.*
  FROM livros l
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT AVG(l2.price) AS media
                     FROM livros l2) m
 WHERE l.price > m.media;
```

Uma terceira forma é realizar o cálculo da média com o `WITH`:

```
WITH media AS (
  SELECT AVG(l2.price) AS media
    FROM livros l2
)
SELECT l.*
  FROM livros l
 WHERE l.price > (SELECT m.media
                    FROM media m);
```

Comment: Qual o significado desse (15,2)?

Comment: @M.Amaral o `15` é o tamanho da parte inteira do número e o `2` é o máximo de casas decimais que serão armazenadas

Comment: O responsável pelo `downvote` pode explicar por que a resposta estaria errada? Não entendo o `downvote` sem explicação e motivo.